# What is the best way to check if all bits are 1?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bit-manipulation, bit

I thought this would be easy due to ~, but ~ just returns a negative value of 2^x rather than 0.

Comment: How many bits are you testing? `1` has all bits set, provided you only expect 1 bit. Remember that Python integers are *arbitrarily sized*, there is no fixed number of bits in a Python integer.

Comment: Do you want to return `true` for numbers like `3`, `7`, `15` etc? (binary 11, 111, 1111)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can modify a standard [bithack](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2) for checking if a number is a power of 2 (numbers one less than a power of 2 are all 1s), with a special case check for zero:

```
def allOnes(n):
    return ((n+1) & n == 0) and (n!=0)

print allOnes(255)
print allOnes(158)
print allOnes(0)
print allOnes(-1)
print allOnes(-2)
```

Output:

```
True
False
False
True
False
```

Comment: This returns true for `1`, `3`, `7`, `15`, etc, which may be unexpected if the OP is thinking in terms of a specific C integer size.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to check if `0` present in `bin(n)`. Here are some examples:

Number having all 1's:

```
>>> n=15
>>> bin(n)
'0b1111'
>>> bin(n)[2:]
'1111'
>>> '0' in bin(n)[2:]
False
```

Number having 1 or more 0's:

```
>>> n=5
>>> bin(n)
'0b101'
>>> bin(n)[2:]
'101'
>>> '0' in bin(n)[2:]
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the languages used MSB (most significant bit) as signed value bit. For example 00000001 in binary is 1 in decimal and 10000011 in binary as -125 in decimal (because of MSB is 1 (-128) & 00000011 is 3 in decimal (-128 + 3 = -125)).

Therefore a binary number whose all bits are 1 is equivalent to -1 in decimal.
So simply if the byte_value is a signed integer,

```
if(byte_value = -1)
{
    printf("All One's");
}
else
{
    printf("All Not One's");
}
```

Otherwise

```
if(byte_value = 255)
{
    printf("All One's");
}
else
{
    printf("All Not One's");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is the XOR (`^`) operator, and not the bitwise NOT (`~`) operator you tried (since that just reverts every bit). Since you mentioned the `~` operator as your initial approach, I assume you want to find out if all bits are 1 in an integer by comparing with an integer with all 1's. Perhaps you are optimising for speed.

The XOR operator will return a 1 only when either of the bits in the operands are 1. Consequently, it will give a 1 wherever any of the bits are 0.

```
>>> 100 ^ 000
100
>>> 100 ^ 100
0
>>> 111 ^ 101
10
>>> 111 ^ 111
0
```

(As you see the resulting integer is not left padded, but it doesn't matter for our purposes.)

The only 'gotcha' is that you need to know the amount of bits in your number in advance.

Then you could check if all bits in it are 1's, by seeing if the resulting number is anything above 0. If it is, then you know not all bits are 1.

Example:

`someNumberWithThreeBits ^ 111 == 0` will return True whenever all bits in someNumberWithThreeBits are 1, and false otherwise.

PS: Please note that 000 ^ 000 would also return 0. But you won't encounter that in this case, unless you decide to compare against 000 instead of 111.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @samgak's answer in response to @Martjin Pieters's comment about specific integer sizes, if the requirement is that all bits for a specific size are 1, then our test needs to be modified. Imagine, for example, that we want to test that a [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble)-sized integer is all 1 in binary representation:

```py
In [2]: def all_ones_nibble(to_test: int) -> bool:
   ...:     assert 0 <= to_test < (1 << 4)
   ...:     # bin(1 << 4) == "0b10000", therefore bin((1 << 4) - 1) == "0b1111"
   ...:     return to_test == (1 << 4) - 1
   ...:

In [3]: all_ones_nibble(int("0", base=2))
Out[3]: False

In [4]: all_ones_nibble(int("1", base=2))
Out[4]: False

In [5]: all_ones_nibble(int("1111", base=2))
Out[5]: True
```

Of course, it's a bit silly to limit ourselves to nibbles, so let's generalize to arbitrary sizes:

```py
In [6]: def all_ones_for_size(to_test: int, size: int) -> bool:
   ...:     return to_test == (1 << size) - 1
   ...:

In [7]: all_ones_for_size(int("1111", base=2), 4)
Out[7]: True

In [8]: all_ones_for_size(int("11111111", base=2), 8)
Out[8]: True

In [9]: all_ones_for_size(int("11111110", base=2), 8)
Out[9]: False
```

Finally, just for fun, let's use @riteshtch's technique to achieve the same result:

```py
In [10]: def all_ones_for_size_using_strs(to_test: int, size: int) -> bool:
    ...:     # NOTE: using a format string obviates the need to shave off "0b".
    ...:     # For example, f"{int('1111', base=2):b}" == "1111", whereas
    ...:     # bin(int("1111", base=2)) == "0b1111"
    ...:     as_bin_str = f"{to_test:b}"
    ...:     return len(as_bin_str) == size and not "0" in as_bin_str
    ...:

In [11]: all_ones_for_size_using_strs(int("11111110", base=2), 8)
Out[11]: False

In [12]: all_ones_for_size_using_strs(int("11111111", base=2), 8)
Out[12]: True

In [13]: all_ones_for_size_using_strs(int("1111", base=2), 8)
Out[13]: False
```

Note that this answer uses python 3 with [type annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), which will not work with python 2.7, but as python 2 has long-since been sunsetted, hopeful future viewers will find the modern code more useful.